# Codenameone Plugin not Loaded in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, codenameone

I am trying to load the Codenameone Plugin to Android Studio 2.1 but it is giving an error Codenameone Plugin not Loaded(Required Plugin AntSupport is not enabled).

But, in the jetbrains site, it is mentioned that it is compatible with Android Studio.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7357?pr=androidstudio

Kindly, advise if codenameone can be used in Android Studio.
Secondly, how much effort will it take to migrate apps built in Android Studio to IntellJ IDEA IDE.(If codenameone doesn't work).

Thirdly, is it a good idea to use codenameone or to learn SWIFT and do ios apps from scratch.

Thanks
Sourav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [download page](https://www.codenameone.com/download.html) explicitly excludes Android Studio from the supported platforms. Unfortunately Google seems to declare that it supports some features (such as Ant) which makes the plugin "seem" to work there but they don't really support those things.